# Notifications from other user accounts not clearing?

Tags: notifications, multi-user

I have made an account on my Nexus 7 for my mum, and she has set a password on it. Her GMail account syncs to it, and I sometimes see notifications on the screen when I am using my account.

This wouldn't normally be an issue, but it would seem that I cannot actually clear them correctly. Observe the screenshots below:

[image: Picture 1]

[image: Picture 2]

On picture one, you can see the GMail icon indicating that there is a notification there, and on picture 2 you can see the gap where the notification is supposed to be.

The gap appears when I select the notification, or swipe it away.

My question: Is there a way for me to clear the notifications from another user account properly?

Comment: What ROM are you running?

Comment: @ZnewmaN ParanoidAndroid

Comment: It looks like there is at least [one other user](http://www.reddit.com/r/Nexus10/comments/173o9o/anybody_with_paranoid_android_and_multiple_users/) out there with the same issue